# How do I do my Pyramid number pattern recursively?

Tags: java

I have to make this pattern using recursive methods
I have it printing out the numbers not correctly
in main I call it like this 
int n = 5; 
a.pattern(n, n);

```
    static void print_space(int space) 
{ 
    // base case 
    if (space == 0) 
        return; 
    System.out.print(" "); 

    // recursively calling print_space() 
    print_space(space - 1); 
} 

// function to print numbers 
static void print_numbers(int numbers) 
{ 
    // base case 
    if (numbers == 0) 
        return; 
    System.out.print("1 "); 

    // recursively calling numbers() 
    print_numbers(numbers - 1); 
} 

// function to print the pattern 
static void pattern(int n, int num) 
{ 
    // base case 
    if (n == 0) 
        return; 
    print_space(n - 1); 
    print_numbers(num - n + 1); 
    print_numbers(num - n); 
    System.out.println(""); 

    // recursively calling pattern() 
    pattern(n - 1, num); 
} 
}
```

it should look like this at the end, but i have it like this

```
    1                          1
   212                        211
  32123                      32121
                            4321321
```

and so on...
Thankyou!!!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the program which creates the shown output, even if it is not what you finally want.

Comment: What makes you think that recursion is the right tool to achieve the desired output? If it is "because teacher wants", then please quote the whole assignment in full, literally and as text. And apply the compromise described here in that case please https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Yunnosch I posted what my code shows on the bottom where i show what it should look like

Comment: I see what you code outputs. I want you to turn the code fragments you have shown into a [mcve] which demonstrates how you create that output. For that, at least the root call to `pattern()` is missing.

Comment: You got an answer which is mixed loop and recursive. You probably have to clarify whether the uber-recursive concept of your code is required or whether mixing in a few loops is allowed. Showing the full assignment description might help to judge that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Pyramid ...

```
*********1*********
********212********
*******32123*******
******4321234******
*****543212345*****
****65432123456****
***7654321234567***
**876543212345678**
*98765432123456789*
```

… is the result of this recursive approach with no methods for spaces and numbers:

```
public class RecursivePyramid {

    public static void WriteOutPyramidLevel(int level,int height) {

        // Need counter in loops 
        int counter;

        // Writing spaces in front - using asterix for visible debugging
        for (counter=height ;counter > level; counter-- ) 
          System.out.print("*");

        // Writing numbers in front
        for (counter=level ;counter > 1; counter-- ) 
            System.out.print(counter);                    

        // Writing central «line» in Pyramid    
        System.out.print(1);

        // Writing numbers after central line
        for (counter=2 ;counter <= level; counter++ ) 
            System.out.print(counter);

        // Writing spaces after central line - can of course be removed   
        for (counter=level ;counter < height; counter++) 
            System.out.print("*"); 

        // Line finished
        System.out.println();

        // If below height of Pyramid go again - max 9 allowed 
        if (level < height && level < 9)
          WriteOutPyramidLevel(level+1,height);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] parameters) {

        WriteOutPyramidLevel(1,10);        
    }
}
```